# Multiple user type in woo-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can I set woo-commerce in such a way that the admin can create multiple type of user or the user can login as different user type and as the user logs in the woo-commerce identifies the user type and display the price defined for that user types.
For eg: The admin defines three usertypes(normal, shops with contract, shops without contract) and the price of a product is different for all user types. If normal user signs in then it should show one price, if shops with contract signs in it should show another price)..

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this in the past, where i had user types like customer, wholesale dealer etc. If you have a fixed discount percentage for each user type the best would be to use this plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-pricing/

But i you dont want to use percentages or want to have specific price for each product then you will have to buy one of these plugins

1. "WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing", its a pretty famous plugin from woocommerce. A bit expensive but you might already be using it.
2. Or a cheaper solution would be 
   http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-prices-by-user-role/8562616